# Can't figure out this loop behavior

Tags: c

I was working on a file processing project where the user would specify how many times he wants to make an input and the contents will be stored in a file in a tabular format. My code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    int n;
    FILE *fptr;
    fptr=fopen("input.txt", "w");

    if(fptr==NULL)
         printf("The file could not be opened.");

    printf("\nFile opened successfully.");

    printf("\nHow many inputs do you want to make?");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    printf("\nEnter contents: \n\n");

    char name[50];
    int age;
    float salary;
    int i;

    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
       printf("\nName(Not more than 50 character): ");
       gets(name);

       if(name[strlen(name)-1]=='\n')
            name[strlen(name)-1]='\0';

       printf("\nAge: ");
       scanf("%d", &age);

       printf("\nSalary: ");
       scanf("%f", &salary);

       fprintf(fptr, "%s\t\t%d\t$%.2f\n", name, age, salary);
    }
}
```

The problem I encounter is the loop doesn't execute properly. I can't enter the name. It skips name and proceeds directly to take age input. I tried fgets(), scanf("%[^\n]s, name) with no avail. So I hope I can get some help here. Regards.

Comment: Enable compiler warnings, maybe. Voting to close as simple typo.

Comment: And please note that there is no function called `gets` in the C language, it was made obsolete 17 years ago and it was completely removed 5 years ago. Your source of learning C is completely outdated.

Comment: It was a typo. Thanks for pointing it out. No need to call names for that.

Comment: @Masquerade007 Replace `gets(name);` with `int c; while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF); if(scanf("%49[^\n]", name) != 1) fputs("Failed to scan name!", stderr);`

Answer (score 5):

Before the loop you do

```
scanf("%d", &n);
```

That reads the number, but not the newline you terminate the input with, leaving the newline in the input buffer. So in the loop when you do

```
gets(name);
```

it reads that newline as an empty line. You need to skip all left-over characters, including the newline, from the previous `scanf` call. For example you could have a loop where you read one character at a time until you have read the newline.

---

As a side-note: Don't use `gets`. It's dangerous, has been deprecated since the C99 standard, and in the latest C11 standard removed completely. The recommended replacement is `fgets`.

Comment: Yeah I don't normally use gets() because it caused a lot of trouble on my previous projects. I began with scanf("%[^\n]s", name) and fgets(name, sizeof(name), stdin) but they didn't work so eventually I tried with gets() and when I posted the problem here it remained in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
   scanf ("%s", &name);
```

That worked for me... if it doesn't, post the output it gives you and I will try to help more.

Also, definitely see WhozCraig's comment and fix that bug too.

Comment: scanf("%s", name) doesn't allow storing white spaces. I tried that in the first place and it only stored the first part of the name. And that was when I omitted the loop.